# Java: anonymous class as subclass from existing implementing an interface?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have `interface IA`, `interface IB extends IA` and `class A implements IA`.

Now I want to create an anonymous class which extends from `A` and implements `IB`.

How would that look like? I thought about something like this:

```
new A() implements IB { /* ... */ }

( Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from A to IB )
```

or:

```
new IB() extends A { /* ... */ }

( Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) )
```

Or is it not possible to create something like that as an anonymous class?

Comment: how doesn't it work?  what error are you getting?

Comment: I think your design is wrong.Class A already offers the functionality of IA and you want it to implement also IB that extends IA? Class A should just implement IB

Comment: Class A should not (and does not and can not) implement IB (because it must not be abstract).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could create an abstract, named inner class that combined the two and extend that with your anonymous class.

```
   private static abstract class AB extends A implements IB {};
    ...
   new AB() {};
```

Bit clumsy, but I don't think you can implement both.